# how to interact with a `select` input with PAMIE?

Tags: python, windows, internet-explorer, automation, pamie

How do I interact with a `select` box using PAMIE?

Comment: and also a good place to find docs on this if possible..

Answer (score 0):

It is `ie.listBoxSelect`, using the source code as documentation.